# Issue communicating with Arduino through Processing

Tags: java, arduino, processing

I have a phototransistor and an LED, when I test in Arduino I do get readings from the phototransistor, but when trying to get the same readings in Processing I just get continuous 0’s. Can any one help? I’ve placed the code below. The phototransistor is connected to port A1. Thanks!

```
import cc.arduino.*;
import org.firmata.*;
import processing.serial.*;


int PhotoPin1 = 1;
Arduino port;
float W= 0;
void setup(){
  port= new Arduino(this, Arduino.list()[17], 9600);
  port.pinMode(PhotoPin1, Arduino.INPUT);
}

void draw() {

  float w_sensorRaw1= port.analogRead(PhotoPin1);
  println(w_sensorRaw1);
  println(W);
  delay(1000);
}
```

Comment: I believe you need to install Firmata on the Arduino. Did you do that?

Comment: @JohnnyMopp yes Firmata is installed. I can run other programs that involve reading Arduino ports which work but for some reason this doesn't work

Comment: I'm not too familiar with Processing (I have worked with Arduino). I suggest you delete this question and ask over at [arduino.se]. You might have better luck there.

Comment: @JohnnyMopp Processing questions are off-topic there.